# Filtrar una query en RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Necesito filtrar una query en rails para obtener el `total_amount` de unas subscripciones pagas.

Mi problema es que al traer los datos, se me están sumando todos los invoices de un user "A"(pagadas, no pagadas), y se me muestran en todos los demás usuarios. Aclaro que es el único user que tiene facturas en general.

Es decir:

- A monto: 100
- B monto: 100

Cuando en la realidad seria.

- A monto:100
- B monto:0

Esto es lo que hice:
**users_controller**

```
@invoices_total = 
  current_account.users.kept.created_desc
    .select(:id, :email, 'SUM(invoices.amount_cents/100) AS invoices_total')
    .joins(:subscription, :invoices).group(:id, :email)
```

> Me agrupa los invoices por id e email de usuario y me suma todos los invoices que hay

**users/index.html.erb**

```
<%= @invoices_total.first.invoices_total %>
```

> Me muestra en todos los users el invoice de mi primer id. Lo que quiero es que me muestre por cada user la suma correspondiente a las facturas pagas de ese usuario.

Si pongo `<%= @invoices_total.user.invoices_total %>` me responde `NoMethodError in Admin::Users#index undefined method ´user'`

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes en `@invoices_total` es una colección de users, no un usuario único (incluso si viniera solo uno), por eso te arroja el `NoMethodError`. Por tanto tienes que iterar en él para mostrar el valor de todos los usuarios de la colección. Algo como:

```
<% @invoices_total.each do |user| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= user.id %></li>
    <li><%= user.email %></li>
    <li><%= user.invoices_total %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```